# How to adjust the path of a Public Folder?

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders

Exchange 2010... we were playing with public folders, and wound up with some root level public folders that we wish to now nest in a subfolder.

For example, we have an "/IT Schedule" public folder now that we wish to nest into "/IT/IT Schedule", so we don't have the root level cluttered up.

Every search I've done on "moving public folder" winds up on the same technet pages showing how to replicate across multiple databases, or to migrate from 2007 to 2010, etc.

There has to be a simple way to do this, even if it means making a new one that's nested, and then copying the stuff over, and killing off the old one... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just moving it from an Outlook client?

Comment: uhhh... problem solved. Too deep in the forest I suppose ;) Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...